# Facing some issues while creating a function inside the class

Tags: python, oop

Here i am creating a function named as apply_raise inside the employee class. But when i am calling the function with one of the instance such as emp_1.apply_raise() ,why it is not returning any result ?It should show me an increment of 4% ??

```py
class Employee:
    
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first+'.'+last+'@company.com'
        self.pay = pay
        
    def fullname(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last))
    
    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * 1.04)
```

Comment: how should it return something when there's no `return` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Add `return self.pay` at the end of the `apply_raise` function:

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first+'.'+last+'@company.com'
        self.pay = pay
    def fullname(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last))
    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * 1.04)
        return self.pay
```